# Explain Hubble's law using proper distance and comoving distance

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

[image]

As far as I can understand, Hubble's law has the form of V(to)=HoDo at a close distance. The meaning of this equation is as follows.
For example, when z=0.01, the emitted photons arrive at us and tell us the speed and distance measured at now. That is, the distance to this galaxy is a(to)X.

My question is as follows:
When observing a distant galaxy, is its proper distane a(to)X or a(t)X?
( X is comoving distance)

As far as I understand, I think we should use a(to) because we see photons arriving now, whether it's a galaxy far away.